# How to exclude MFC bar from dock state

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there an easy way to exclude a control bar from the dock state saved by an MFC frame window?

We have a dock bar whose visibility is controlled by some other state and the loading of dock state is interfering with the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have do dock/undock the specific bar **after** your call to "LoadBarState" using [DockControlBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc9dywd6(VS.80).aspx) or [FloatControlBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkywsyh1(VS.80).aspx) (depending on the *other state*).

Another (more kind of hacky) option is to remove the specific registry key with the settings **after** your call to "SaveBarState". The dock state is saved here:

> HKLM\Software*\companyname\applicationname*

There it has a key for each control bar.

Answer (score 2):

Override these and make them return FALSE

```
virtual BOOL LoadState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName = NULL, int nIndex = -1, UINT uiID = (UINT) -1);

virtual BOOL SaveState(LPCTSTR lpszProfileName = NULL, int nIndex = -1, UINT uiID = (UINT) -1);
```